# HTML file does not load style.css file

Tags: html, css

I am doing a small webpage but now I ran into a small problem. My html file does not load the style-file even though they are placed in the same folder. I checked the css file in w3schools and it worked fine. I know that this topic has been around but I was not able to solve my problem by reading these. My html coding looks like this

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Smile's app</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>

 <body>
 <h2>Hello Dude</h2>
   <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a> 

   <blockquote>Nerds like us are allowed to be unironically enthusiastic about stuff. Nerds are allowed to love stuff - like, jump-up-and-down-in-your-chair-can't-control-yourself love it. When people call other people nerds, mostly what they're saying is "You like stuff", which is not a good insult at all. Like, "You are too enthusiastic about the miracle of human consciousness".</blockquote>
   <div class="cite">John Green</div>

   <li><a href="static/indexx.html">page2</a></li>

 </body>
</html>
```

the css coding looks like this

```
blockquote {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cite {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

Noe I've found out by the web console style editor that the following errors exists

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

I relly do hope that someone can help me out.

Comment: have you looked in your console to see if there are any errors? to see if the file is being loaded?

Comment: `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` ? without closing slash

Comment: Are you linking the file from the right directory? If it was located in a subfolder, you might try: <link href="subfolder/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Is it that only when loading from file that it doesn't work? What about if you write it in the `style` block?

Comment: is your style.css in the same folder as your html file? you might need to change the path to /style.css or ../style.css or ../css/style.css

Comment: Make your you haven't misspelt the actual file name - it's a more common problem than you think. Other than that make sure that `style.css` is definitely in the same folder.

Comment: It does not help to remove the closing slash. The html and css file are placed in the same folder.

When I'm writing the css coding directly into the html file it works fine. So it is a matter of loading a css file. 

I am all sure of that everything is spelled the correct way

Comment: **Check your browser's error console.** There's undoubtably a 404 there related to the stylesheet.

Comment: In the browser "style editor" I am getting the following

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">

<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>

How can I make these changes?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following things.. (Though you may have checked it or it seems to be silly)

- Make sure the CSS file is in the same directory as your HTML
- Make sure the name of your CSS file is `style.css`

If all this doesn't work, add your CSS in the style tag which is in the head tag, like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Smile's app</title>
  <style>
  blockquote {
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .cite {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-large;
  }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h2>Hello Dude</h2>
   <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a> 

   <blockquote>Nerds like us are allowed to be unironically enthusiastic about stuff. Nerds are allowed to love stuff - like, jump-up-and-down-in-your-chair-can't-control-yourself love it. When people call other people nerds, mostly what they're saying is "You like stuff", which is not a good insult at all. Like, "You are too enthusiastic about the miracle of human consciousness".</blockquote>
   <div class="cite">John Green</div>

   <li><a href="static/indexx.html">page2</a></li>

 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this is helpful (Though it was silly and basic).

Note: Even the smallest, silliest, basic things can make a difference.

Comment: Well, it works this way. But later on when I am adding more to the css file then it is going to be messy if I should put all the changes in the html file. So I really want to make it work by a separate css file.

Comment: Be absolutely sure of the directory , if it's in the previous directory then it will be like `    ../previous/style.css    `. then check if the file is really a CSS file. but we can't really say what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend having a look at the folder structure.

Are you developing in a local environment or somwhere remote?

Are you using some kind of Webserver (for example Apache) or are you accessing the files via `file:///`?

As you say:

> In the browser "style editor" I am getting the following
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> 
> <title>404 Not Found</title> 
> <h1>Not Found</h1> 
> <p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
> ```
>
> How can I make these changes?

It seems to me that the server has no access to the css file. 
Have you checked the access rights and the owner of the file?

I'm sorry that is all I can recommend now, and probably you already have tried id yourself, but I personally think that the solution must be somwhere on the file system, because both of the files seem to be correct.